# XCTest: Tap "Done" button in SFSafariViewController

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcuitest, sfsafariviewcontroller, uitest

I'm opening a SFSafariViewController and can't find the "Done" Button to leave Safari again.

Also if I try to solve it with a swipeRight XCode creates code that it can't use in a test afterwards

```
let element = app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 2)
    element.swipeRight()
```

Any idea how to dismiss SFSafariViewController? (I don't need access to elements in the browser).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let doneButton = app.buttons["Done"]
waitUntilElementExists(element: doneButton)
doneButton.tap()
```

The waitUntilElementExists I think its the key to making it work, I wait 60 seconds tops.